# Issue with SQLite query?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

First. verry sorry about my english. if you dont understand what i mean pls notice me.
i have a problem with this code, but I dont know why

```
public Cursor fetchReminderByMaterial(String table_name, String label, String key_material_name) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, table_name, null, key_material_name + "=" + label, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I have an error like `no such column label`.
how can I solve it?

update
this is my fuction to creating table

```
String conectionSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ DATABASE_CONNECTION_TABLE +"(";
                            conectionSql += ""+ KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
                            conectionSql += ""+ KEY_FOOD_NAME +",";
                            conectionSql += ""+ KEY_MATERIAL_NAME +")";

    mDbConection.createTable(conectionSql); // Tao bang
```

and that is how i use it

```
Cursor c = mDbConnection.fetchReminderByMaterial(
            DATABASE_CONNECTION_TABLE, "material", KEY_MATERIAL_NAME);
```

thank you to listening

Comment: You probably added that column **after** the database was first created.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you used to create the table.

Comment: What are the values of the `key_column_two` and `label` variables?

Comment: Frank.N. Stein >> i dont think so. because that database already existed when i do some stuff in another activity. i just make some query on a table already existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is written pretty clear - you database do not have a column "label". Check your SQLiteOpenHelper `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`  that you're creating the database with the right scheme. And check the parameters in method

```
public Cursor fetchReminderByLabel(String table_name, String label,
        String key_column_two)
```

key_column_two that you pass the correct column name

Comment: i am already check it many time. i also check database in DDMS. i just use static final parameter to query it.

Comment: Try to make a rawQuery with correct hardcoded table values and colum like mDbConnection.rawQuery("select * from sometable where somecolumn=?",label); Just for the test purposes and see if it is working as intended

Comment: yes. i am not good in hardcode but i will try it. thank you so much